# convert only number strings to integer in python list

Tags: python

I have below python list

```
a= ['2','3','44','22','cat','2.2','-3.4','Mountain']
```

How can i get below output with one command (convert only numeric strings to numeric)

```
a = [2,3,44,22,'cat',2.2,-3.4,'Mountain']
```

Comment: What is the intended usage of the output list?

Comment: i want to add to excel sheet with openpyxl so i can easily work with excel sheet. Otherwise i would need to change data manually in excel sheet later

Comment: Could you add a plain python tag please?

Comment: Ok i just added the tag python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting to integer if numeric. For floats convert it blindly and if there is an exception, we can assume its a string.

```
foo = []
for i in a:
    if i.isnumeric():
        foo.append(int(i))
    else:
        try:
            foo.append(float(i))
        except ValueError:
            foo.append(i)

print(foo)
```

Output:
`[2, 3, 44, 22, 'cat', 2.2, -3.4, 'Mountain']`

**UPDATE**
A shorter version of the code would be:

```
foo = []
for i in a:
    try:
        foo.append(int(i) if float(i).is_integer() else float(i))
    except ValueError:
        foo.append(i)

print(foo)
```

Comment: Thanks.. what i needed

Answer (score 1):

The brute force way to do it is to go through the whole list and convert item by item. If the conversion fails, it will raise a ValueError exception which you can catch.

```
a= ['2','3','44','22','cat','2.2','-3.4','Mountain']

# enumerate is a handy function which gives you both the index and item for the 
# contents of an iterable.
for i, item in enumerate(a):

    try:
        a[i] = int(float(item))
    except ValueError:
        a[i] = item

print(a)
```

which gives

```
[2, 3, 44, 22, 'cat', 2, -3, 'Mountain']
```

Comment: This does not seem to convert `'2.2'` and `-3.4` correctly.

Comment: @yashtodi94, you're right. I thought to OP wanted integers. Your answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code

```
b = [float(i) if i.lstrip('-').replace('.', '', 1).isdigit() else i for i in a  ]
print(b)
```

Comment: Thanks.. but its showing integers as float too